# How to use classes declared in another plugin?

Tags: plugins, oop

I'm developing a Wordpress Woocommerce plugin. On my local environment it works fine but I have problems when adding the plugin to a replica of the prod environment. I am new to wordpress and not very familiar with web dev (I'm a Java programmer).

In the plugin file, I instantiate a class from the Woocommerce plugin package like this:

```
$coupon = new WC_Coupon($some_code);
```

In the local environment (php 5.4.10 , Woocommerce 2.0.13, Wordpress 3.6) it's fine. In the production environment (php 5.4.10 , Woocommerce 1.6.5.2, Wordpress 3.4.2) I have the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'WC_Coupon' not found
```

I have tried including the file where the WC_Coupon class is defined but then the error becomes

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WC_Coupon
```

So what is the proper way to use classes declared in another plugin?

Note: upgrading is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check if the class exists, but before that you have to *wait* that all plugin are loaded: no one can assure that your plugin is loaded after WooCommerce.

For run a code from plugin when all plugin are loaded hook into `plugins_loaded` hook.

Be aware that you cannot use this hook in a theme, because when theme load that hook was already fired.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_coupon_init');

function my_coupon_init() {
  if ( class_exists('WC_Coupon') ) {
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($some_code);
    // some code here
  } else {
    add_action('admin_notices', 'wc_not_loaded');
  }
}

function wc_not_loaded() {
    printf(
      '<div class="error"><p>%s</p></div>',
      __('Sorry cannot create coupon because WooCommerce is not loaded')
    );
}
```

Comment: Not sure if in that case `plugins_loaded` is the proper hook. One will have to search when exactly that class is available and hook in _after_ that. Anyway +1

Comment: In this particular case, I am hooking to the deactivation hook `register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate');`. So I can't wait. Can I ask wordpress to load the class if it's not loaded yet?

Comment: Thanks @kaiser. The `WC_Coupon` is loaded by `__construct` of the main `WooCommerce` class (really by `includes()` method directly called by `__construct`) and `WooCommerce` class is instanziate (as singleton) as soon as plugin is loaded. So `plugins_loaded` is proper hook in this case ;)

Comment: Anonymous before core loads? Well done Woo, well done.

Comment: @NathanZ Check `class_exists( 'WC_Coupon' )`. Also please state that you're using this during deactivation... could have saved answering crowd tons of time...

Answer (score 6):

This is too late but I would like to share how to use woocommerce and its classes without having an error class not found.

First is to check if [woocommerce is installed](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-plugin/) and use the `woocommerce_loaded` action hook.

```
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Put your plugin code here

    add_action('woocommerce_loaded' , function (){
         //Put your code here that needs any woocommerce class 
         //You can also Instantiate your main plugin file here 
    });

}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be :

```
 if( class_exists('WC_Coupon') ) $coupon = new WC_Coupon($some_code);
```

It's better to check if class exists before using it, it avoids fatal error if the plugin is disabled.

You can't redeclare a class it's not allowed in PHP.

You can also extend class :

```
class My_WC_Coupon extends WC_Coupon {
   //some code
   //some hook
}
```

But most of the time and in this case with WooCommerce you'd better find a hook in [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-user-guide/getting-started/) that will handle the job.

Comment: If you extend your class via a hook, won't the new class only exist in the scope of the function hook?