# Extend plugin Class through functions.php

Tags: php, pluggable, customization

**Move manual fix applied to plugin source code to theme `functions.php` or as Code Snippet**

I've applied a manual fix to a plugin file.

I'd like to make this fix more accessible and scalable by hooking this through the theme's `functions.php` or adding it as a snippet using a plugin like *Code Snippets*.

**The Manual Fix applied to plugin file (functions as expected):**

```
/**
         * Add admin meta box with actions
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */
        public function add_woo_pdf_metabox()
        {
            global $post;

            if (!$post) {
                return;
            }

            /* Manual Fix Applied */
            $post_type_order = get_post_type( $post );
            echo $post_type_order;

            if ($post_type_order != 'shop_order') {
                return;
            }
            /* End Manual Fix */

            $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

            if (!$order) {
                return;
            }

            $invoice = $this->get_invoice($post->ID);

            if ((is_array($invoice) && !empty($invoice) && $this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled']) || (!is_array($invoice) && $this->opt['woo_pdf_proforma_enabled'] && ($order->status != 'completed' || $this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled'])) || ($this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled'])) {
                add_meta_box('woo_pdf_metabox', __('PDF Invoices', 'woo_pdf'), array($this, 'woo_pdf_metabox_content'), 'shop_order', 'side', 'default');
            }
        }
```

**Adjusted fix saved as Code Snippet using keyword `extends` on plugin Class (does not function):**

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'regulate_pdf_metabox_appearance'); // hook used to call function

function regulate_pdf_metabox_appearance() { // wrapped in function
  if (class_exists('WooPDF')) {

    class WooPDF_custom extends WooPDF {

      /**
      * Add admin meta box with actions
      *
      * @access public
      * @return void
      */
        function add_woo_pdf_metabox() {
          global $post;

          if (!$post) {
            return;
          }

          /* Manual Fix Applied */
          $post_type_order = get_post_type( $post );

          if ($post_type_order != 'shop_order') {
            return;
          }

          $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

          if (!$order) {
            return;
          }

          $invoice = $this->get_invoice($post->ID);

          if ((is_array($invoice) && !empty($invoice) && $this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled']) || (!is_array($invoice) && $this->opt['woo_pdf_proforma_enabled'] && ($order->status != 'completed' || $this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled'])) || ($this->opt['woo_pdf_enabled'])) {
            add_meta_box('woo_pdf_metabox', __('PDF Invoices', 'woo_pdf'), array($this, 'woo_pdf_metabox_content'), 'shop_order', 'side', 'default');
          }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

What is required in the code above to have the same fix work using `extends` and inserting it into the theme's `functions.php` or through a *Code Snippet*?

Comment: How are you using it? Because if you extend a class you have to call the name of the extended class to function as you expected. More info here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: Referring to this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110672/how-to-use-classes-declared-in-another-plugin I've since wrapped it in a function. I am now using `plugins_loaded` hook to call it (question updated) - which I had assumed would call the name of the extended class. This is not working either. Should I be using another hook or filter?

Comment: This answer just create a new object of the `WC_Coupon`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it doesn't address my concern. Do you know of a solution that can address the issue I've demonstrated in the scope of wordpress? A solution pertaining to php in general will be too broad in scope for me unfortunately, since my experience with php is far too limited to put any of that into context without any sort of guidance, and although links to documentation are often helpful, if I have no frame of reference, I struggle to find it very useful.

Comment: The WP way to extend and modify are actions and filters. So what you are doing can only work for code calling the `WooPDF_custom`.

Comment: Is there a better alternative action (or filter) I should be using instead of `'plugins_loaded'`?

Comment: You code example is not showing the possibility of filters. Maybe you can find helpful https://murze.be/2016/02/monkey-patching-in-php-with-patchwork/ .